# PHP Arrays: Extract from CSV

Tags: php, arrays, csv

Hi I'm using a simple import to CSV script that brings information into an array from a CSV file.

The sample output of the print_r($data) statement is:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [Email,Name,"Message Number","Date Added", ...etc ])  => email@email,com,myname,1001,"10/27/16 9:54pm EDT",... etc ) [1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) => Array ( [Email,Name,"Message Number","Date Added",

print_r($data[0])

shows Array ( [Email,Name,"Message Number","Date Added",

I'm trying to isolate the variables but each time I get a null result on the quoted values.

```
$csv="members.csv";
$importer = new CsvImporter($csv,true);
$data = $importer->get();
echo "<pre>";
$n=0;

$messageNumber = $data[$n]['Message Number'];
```

What am I doing wrong?  It should return '1001' in that variable.

**Note: I'm using the class   [CsvImporter on this page in PhP FgetFSV](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)**

Again, what I'm looking for is the definition to isolate an individual variable in an easy way.

Thank you!

**Perhaps someone has a simpler way to read a CSV into a PHP Array than using the above class?**

Comment: Erh, looks like your extraction is wrong, that doesn't look like a proper array.

Comment: Could you show what `print_r($data[0])` and `print_r($data[1])` produces?

Comment: Array ( [Email,Name,"Message Number","Date Added",

Comment: @Viktor noooo, not as a comment - edit your original post instead.

Comment: could you show exact print_r($data) add echo "<pre>" before print_r statement and show the result.

Comment: Show us the part of your code where you extract the data into the array.

Comment: @Viktor ...and `print_r($data[1]) ` as well please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example given in the php docs for `CsvImporter` it's changing the default delimiter to `\t`. Try add `','` as the 3rd param for the class:

```
$importer = new CsvImporter($csv,true, ',');
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
$csv="members.csv";
$importer = new CsvImporter($csv,true, ',');
$data = $importer->get();
echo "<pre>";
$n=0;
$messageNumber = $data[$n]['Message Number']; 
print $messageNumber;
```

Returns the correct '1001' as expected.
The solution is marked above.Thanks to Ross. Simply changing the $importer = new CsvImporter($csv,true, ','); solved the entire puzzle.